# How to call async method from greenlet (playwright)

Tags: python-asyncio, gevent, playwright

My framework (Locust, https://github.com/locustio/locust) is based on gevent and greenlets. But I would like to leverage Playwright (https://playwright.dev/python/), which is built on asyncio.

Naively using Playwrights sync api doesnt work and gives an exception:

```
playwright._impl._api_types.Error: It looks like you are using Playwright Sync API inside the asyncio loop.
Please use the Async API instead.
```

I'm looking for some kind of best practice on how to use async in combination with gevent.

I've tried a couple different approaches but I dont know if I'm close or if what I'm trying to do is even possible (I have some experience with gevent, but havent really used asyncio before)

Edit: I kind of have something working now (I've removed Locust and just directly spawned some greenlets to make it easier to understan). Is this as good as it gets, or is there a better solution?

```
import asyncio
import threading
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright
import gevent


def thr(i):
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(do_stuff(i))
    loop.close()


async def do_stuff(i):
    playwright = await async_playwright().start()
    browser = await playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    page = await browser.new_page()
    await page.wait_for_timeout(5000)
    await page.goto(f"https://google.com")
    await page.close()
    print(i)


def green(i):
    t = threading.Thread(target=thr, args=(i,))
    t.start()
    # t.join() # joining doesnt work, but I couldnt be bothered right now :)



g1 = gevent.spawn(green, 1)
g2 = gevent.spawn(green, 2)
g1.join()
g2.join()
```

Comment: This works, but you're creating a new event loop for every coroutine. The usual way to combine asyncio with threads is to start a single event loop in a dedicated thread, and give it work using [`asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe). (`asyncio.coroutine_threadsafe` returns a `concurrent.futures.Future` with a sync API for retrieving the result.) Haven't tried it with green threads, but it's worth a shot, and might help with the issue you've had with `Thread.join`, since the asyncio thread is never joined.

Comment: Although… playwright is explicitly not thread safe so I’m not sure that would work

Comment: If playwright is not thread-safe, that's _all the more_ reason to go for my proposal. It's about using playwright from a _single_ thread, with asyncio doing the task switching. I expect that how the library is typically used and tested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insipred by @user4815162342 's comment, I went with something like this:

```
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright # need to import this first
from gevent import monkey, spawn
import asyncio
import gevent

monkey.patch_all()
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()


async def f():
    print("start")
    playwright = await async_playwright().start()
    browser = await playwright.chromium.launch(headless=True)
    context = await browser.new_context()
    page = await context.new_page()
    await page.goto(f"https://www.google.com")
    print("done")


def greeny():
    while True:  # and not other_exit_condition
        future = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(f(), loop)
        while not future.done():
            gevent.sleep(1)


greenlet1 = spawn(greeny)
greenlet2 = spawn(greeny)
loop.run_forever()
```

The actual implementation will end up in [Locust](https://github.com/locustio/locust) some day, probably after some optimization (reusing browser instance etc)

Comment: thanks for sharing this. We are using a gevent worker with `RQ` but couldn't quite understand how would one adapt this approach to our use case. The `run_coroutine_threadsafe` method should be the at the bottom-most level? Meaning where the work is actually being done? I ask since our work has deeply nested method calling. wondering where should we actually run the coroutine, and if we should pass the loop all around.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way to integrate asyncio and gevent:

- Run an asyncio loop in a dedicated thread
- Use `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe()` to run a coroutine
- Use `gevent.event.Event` to wait until the coroutine resolves

```py
import asyncio
import threading
import gevent

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
loop_thread = threading.Thread(target=loop.run_forever, daemon=True)
loop_thread.start()

async def your_coro():
  # ...

def wait_until_complete(coro):
  future = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(coro, loop)

  event = gevent.event.Event()
  future.add_dome_callback(lambda _: event.set())
  event.wait()

  return future.result()

result = wait_until_complete(your_coro())
```